# Enterprise Architect: Default settings for test artifact rendering possible?

Tags: modeling, application-settings, enterprise-architect

for Use Cases and Test Classes/Suites, Sparx EA does support a rectangle notation instead of the default elliptic appearance.
(As described here: http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/modeling_languages/usingrectanglenotation.html)

Is it possible to make the rectangular notation the [ EA-wide | project-wide | package-wide ] *default* for test classes/suites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no answer came in here, I posted the same question to the Sparx forum and a user answered it: You can use [EA's API](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/sdk_for_enterprise_architect/theautomationinterface.htm) to [achieve that, as there is no such setting.](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1359389297)